# Is there any difference between the null conditional operator and a dedicated null check?

Tags: c#

For instance:

- I have an instance that may or may not be null.
- I want to get the value of one of its bool members.

I wrote some awful code like this:

```
var someVar = (someInstance != null) ? someInstance.boolValue : false;
```

ReSharper suggested two other ways to do the same:

```
var someVar = someInstance?.boolValue ?? false;

var someVar = (someInstance != null) && someInstance.boolValue;
```

Is there any technical reason to prefer either of them, or do they end up doing the exact same?

Comment: Pick your favorite

Comment: Which is more readable to you?

Comment: I know this is about C#, but IntelliJ IDEA suggests this for Kotlin code: `someInstance?.boolValue == true` which should also work in C#

Comment: The compiler *lowers* them all exactly the same way https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UlAygPYC2ApgJIB2AzgC4CGVAxmdrljLt3ogEZEiAG36ChANQZCArmUwBzMnQDcNJcoC+7HFq64EyACyIAsgAoAlJm08AbgwBOiGqUq1GLOQF5EVMgHdEYnJqeiZWS2Ubbmj9CABOM0QzFxD3cLkAQh8qaSEhKwB+Z1dQj1YAOgFhSRk5AC5EADMpNQsovR5kBKTUtzDPQqqxWtlEQuKWoTaOrpwQHuS+sozEbN88gsQAMm2StIHK6okpWXbY+Z7l9MHhmtPvHzoHM9ncXQ0gA

Comment: `var someVar = (someInstance != null) ? someInstance.boolValue : false;` is in my view inferior since there is a double negative ternary (i.e. a ternary with a `!=`). But, other than that specific form, they are all basically the same (assuming `boolValue` returns a `bool`) so pick whichever you prefer.

Comment: I'll pick first one.

Comment: I am not sure the title edit captures the *exact* meaning of the question, however it is better than what it was, feel free to look at the history and change at will

Comment: If it is not just a variable, but an expression (like `(GetSomeInstance() != null) ? GetSomeInstance().boolValue : false;` there **is** a difference: this will evaluate the expression twice, while `GetSomeInstance()?.boolValue ?? false`  will evaluate it only once. Might make a performance and/or semantic difference.

Comment: @ vad842 It's just syntactic sugar to write smaller, cleaner, more readable, and more robust code. Otherwise it is the same. Take what you like. That said in general, for the case provided, the last line of code is in general more appropriate I find. But for direct assignment during declaring at the same time, the null coalescing operator is not needed at all because the boolean is false by default. Therefore `bool someVar = someInstance?.BoolValue;` *does the perfect job and that's all you need* (please don't use var for primitve types: see for example *Effective C# - Item 1* or any article).

Comment: Personally, I prefer equality / inequality operators to specify if `default(bool?)` is treated as true or false; `someInstance?.boolValue != false`

Comment: Thank you all, and thanks @TheGeneral for that tool! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is not to return `null`, but create a "Default" instance of the type. Can be good fit in the scenario where you have default values

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly MyClass Default = new MyClass(false);

    public bool HaveSomething { get; }

    public MyClass(bool haveIt) => HaveSomething = haveIt;
}

// Usage

var someThing = LoadThing(); // Never returns null

if (someThing.HaveSomething)
{
    // some action
}
```

The goal is to check for `null` only once when you load or trying to create an instance, then you can remove null checks from the rest of the application